# What does it mean if the bitwise XOR of the sum and two addends are both negative?

Tags: c, binary

For example, there are 3 variables of long type, we add `a` and `b` and get `s`:

```
long a, b, s;
...
s = a + b
```

Now what does `((s^a) < 0 && (s^b) < 0)` mean?

I saw a check like this in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37c827d9dda4/Python/ceval.c#l1718) of Python:

```
    if (PyInt_CheckExact(v) && PyInt_CheckExact(w)) {
        /* INLINE: int + int */
        register long a, b, i;
        a = PyInt_AS_LONG(v);
        b = PyInt_AS_LONG(w);
        i = a + b;
        if ((i^a) < 0 && (i^b) < 0)
            goto slow_iadd;
        x = PyInt_FromLong(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This code is wrong.**

Assuming the usual 2's-complement rules of bitwise XOR for signed integers, then

```
(s^a) < 0
```

is the case if `s` and `a` have their sign bits set to opposite values. Thus,

```
((s^a) < 0 && (s^b) < 0)
```

indicates that `s` has sign different from both `a` and `b`, which must then have equal sign (pretending 0 is positive). If you added two integers of equal sign and got a result of different sign, there must have been an overflow, so this is an overflow check.

If we assume that signed overflow wraps, then `s` has opposite sign from `a` and `b` exactly when overflow has occurred. However, signed overflow is undefined behavior. Computing `s` is already wrong; we need to check whether the overflow would occur without actually performing the operation.

Python isn't supposed to do this. You can see what it's supposed to do in the [Python 2 source code for `int.__add__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37c827d9dda4/Objects/intobject.c#l472):

```
/* casts in the line below avoid undefined behaviour on overflow */
x = (long)((unsigned long)a + b);
if ((x^a) >= 0 || (x^b) >= 0)
```

It's supposed to cast to unsigned to get defined overflow behavior. The cast-to-unsigned fix was introduced in 5 different places as a result of [issue 7406](https://bugs.python.org/issue7406) on the Python bug tracker, but it looks like they missed a spot, or perhaps `INPLACE_ADD` was changed since then. I've left a message on the tracker.

Comment: What do you mean by "signed overflow is undefined behavior"?

Comment: @satoru: What part do you not understand? Signed overflow, or undefined behavior? Signed overflow is when you perform an operation on signed input and it overflows. Undefined behavior is where the C standard permits the implementation to do anything, up to and including [making demons fly out your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: I've added a link to the file from which I found this snippet.

Comment: @satoru: Huh. Looks like they missed a spot; it's not supposed to do that. I'll check for existing bug reports about that operation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this is possible.

If `(s^a) < 0`, then the sign bit of either `s` or `a` must be a 1, so either `s` or `a` (but not both) must be negative. Same for `s` and `b`. So either `s` is negative and both `a` and `b` are positive, or `s` is positive and both `a` and `b` are negative. Both situations seem impossible.

Unless you count integer overflow/underflow, of course.